# Switching between cellular and WiFi networks in Android

Tags: android

I am interested in knowing Android source code files/classes responsible for automatic switching between WiFi and cellular network when WiFi becomes available/unavailable. I tried searching android source code at android.googlesource.com but could not find any information. Is it something which is done by android platform or linux kernel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) class.

Example

```
String networkStatus = "disconnected";
            int netType = 0;
            try{
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(connectivityManager != null ){
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                    if(networkInfo != null){
                        netType = networkInfo.getType();
                        Log.d("Log", "connetion is available");
                    }else {
                        Log.d("Log", "connetion is  not available");
                        return networkStatus;
                    }

                //  if(networkInfo.isAvailable()){  // Old one
if(networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()){  // New change added here
                        if(netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                            {}
                        else if(netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE )
                            {}
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Log", "checkNetworkConnection" + e.toString());
            return networkStatus;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not want to have the functionality in an app. I am interested in knowing, how android do this automatically, for example, when a connected wifi network suddenly becomes unavailable, phone switches to cellular data. Which part of Android source code/framework files/kernel is responsible for this automatic switching?